# How to protect database connection strings on production environments of ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, encryption, connection-string, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a .NET Core app that is deployed on Ubuntu (using Kestrel behind Nginx).

The app has a database connection string. It is defined empty in appsettings.json and I set it in Kestrel Ubuntu service file as a service environment variable, as per [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
# somevalue was escaped with systemd-escape "value"
Environment=ConnectionStrings__MyDatabaseConnection=somevalue
```

However, my customer does not accept storing the raw string in a file on the server (and they are right).

I could encrypt it but then I have to store the encryption key somewhere on the server, which also is not acceptable - it just pushes the same issue further down the line.

So, I did some search for solutions with a hope to find some de-facto standard or straight-forward "drop-in" solution but, surprisingly, could not find anything.

Here's what I've looked at:

- Secret Manager - not an option; just pushes the same raw text to the user's profile "as is". Meant for development only.
- Azure Vault - not an option, we don't use Azure. There are similar powerful systems, such as Hashicorp Vault, but it seems an overkill to use something like that (a full-blown web service with non-trivial configuration and possible hidden caveats) for a single connection string.

This connection string protection issue is the final, seemingly simple roadblock that prevents the project from being accepted by the customer.

There should be a simple solution to add to my project and also to provide the customer's administrators with a tool to encrypt the connection string in the Kestrel service file.

What other .net core developers are using to protect connection strings on production GNU/Linux servers?

Comment: @RoarS.  Thanks, I guess that was a lead to Hashicorp Vault. I guess, I'll have to use it then, but still it seems an overkill to install such a large-ish system (essentially a separate web service) to store a single connection string on a single server. I hoped for something simpler.

Comment: I found this one kind of interesting, custom solution: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/09/26/decrypting-config-settings.aspx